# How to fix this function please?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to code a function that takes as input a list of tuples, the number of tuples, and two numbers. This function should return `True` if the two given numbers exist in one of the tuples in our list.

For example : `ma_fonction(l,n,i,j)`

- `l`: list of tuples
- `i` and `j` two numbers between `0` and `n-1` and `i != j`

I tried this code:

```
def ma_fonction(l,n,i,j):
    checker = False
    for item in l :

        if ( i in item and j in item ):
            cheker = True
            return True 
        else: 
            return False

ma_fonction([(0,1), (5,2), (4,3)], 6, 2, 5)
```

But it doesn't work. What should I add or change?

---

I tried this ( somehow i didnt copy all my work in my question )
This is my work:

```
def ma_fonction(l,n,i,j):
    checker = False
    if((i!=j )and (0<=i<=n-1 )and( 0<=j<=n-1) ):
        for item in l :

            if ( i in item and j in item ):
                cheker=True
                return True 
            else: 
                return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def ma_fonction(l,n,i,j):
    for item in l :
        if ( i in item and j in item ):
            return True 
    return False
```

The reason your solution is not working is because you are returning `False` at the first element of the list that doesn't match with i and j. What you need to do is return `False` if and only if you looked in all the elements of the list and you couldn't find a match.

Answer (score 1):

change your function to this:

```
def foo(l,n,i,j):
    for item in l: 
        if (i in item and j in item):
            return True 
    return False
```

You go over all tuples, and if i and j are in the tuple, you return True.
If it went over all tuples and didn't find a match, we can be sure that we can return False.

And this implementation really doesn't need the parameter n

Answer (score 1):

The logic is that for each tuple in this list, check whether it contains the number i and j. If yes, then return True; if no, continue check the next tuple. Once you finish checking every tuple, and it turns out that there is no satisfied tuple, then return False.

```
def ma_fonction(l,n,i,j):
    for item in l :
        if ( i in item and j in item ):
            return True 
    return False
```